# Удаляются куки после обновления страниы

Tags: javascript, cookie

Не понимаю, почему после обновления страницы удаляются cookie сайта. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```js
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime();
var ref_exp = time + 1000 * 5184000;
var access_exp = time + 1000 * 244800;
document.location.href = "https://testsite.com/template/feed.html";
now.setTime(access_exp);
document.cookie = "at=test;expires=" + now + ";path=/";
now.setTime(ref_exp);
document.cookie = "rt=test;expires=" + now + ";path=/";
```

Comment: Так у вас сначала идет обновление страницы, а потом установка куки. Соответственно, во время обновления кук еще нет.

Comment: Страница загружается и показывает 2 куки. Как только страница обновляется пользователем кук становится 0.

Comment: @Filvin Stepan Kasyanenko абсолютно прав(пока писал ответ, он Вам корректно указал на ошибку). Вы либо устанавливаете, куки в другом месте, но в текущем скрипте у Вас просто не успевают записаться данные в cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас используется смена локации до записи в cookie `document.location.href = "https://testsite.com/template/feed.html";`.
В это время страница перезагружается и всё начинается сначала, не успевая сделать записи. 
 Перенесите запись в `cookie` до `document.location.href`

```js
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime();
var ref_exp = time + 1000 * 5184000;
var access_exp = time + 1000 * 244800;
now.setTime(access_exp);
document.cookie = "at=test;expires=" + now + ";path=/";
now.setTime(ref_exp);
document.cookie = "rt=test;expires=" + now + ";path=/";
document.location.href = "https://testsite.com/template/feed.html";
```

Comment: Куки ставятся, но ровно до того момента, как пользователь обновит страницу. После этого куки слетают.

Comment: @Filvin используйте мой вариант - протестировал у себя, ничего не слетает.

Comment: У меня изначально так было. Куки вообще не ставились.